# rvm gets "undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass" installing Ruby on macos

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 3.0.x using rvm on a 2018 Mac mini.  I couldn't install 3.0.4, 3.0.2, 3.0.0 (then I tried 2.7.5, just to see if the issue was specific to 3.0.x). All 4 of these installs failed with exactly the same error:

```
    ruby-3.0.4 - #post-configuration - please wait
    ruby-3.0.4 - #compiling - please wait
    Error running '__rvm_make -j6',
    please read /Users/macmini/.rvm/log/1652638839_ruby-3.0.4/make.log
    There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

make.log ends with the following lines

```
    generating encdb.h
    builtin_binary.inc updated
    compiling builtin.c
    encdb.h updated
    x86_64-darwin21-fake.rb updated
    NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
      <main> at -e:2
    make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Error 1
    +__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

I get this same failure on Big Sur and on Monterey 12.3.1.

There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5124) that has 8 people reporting what sounds like the same error between 8/10/21 and 2/24/22, with no one reporting a solution (except a suggestion of switching to rbenv).  Two of these posts have lines at the end of make.log that are extremely similar to what I'm seeing:

```
    encdb.h updated
    NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
      -e at -e:2
    make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Error 1
    +__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!   Thanks!!!

Wayne Vucenic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.  My current & default ruby was set to jruby-9.2.9.0.  I set it to ruby-2.7.6 and now 3.0.4 installs without any issues.

Comment: I had the exact same issue when my default global ruby was jruby 9.2.20.1, and I was attempting to install Ruby 3.1.2.  Switched global to Ruby 3.0.4, and the install worked.
I was using asdf-ruby, not rvm, but the problem was the same.  You can't install Ruby from JRuby, apparently.

Comment: Amazing that this was the issue! Thank you!!!

Comment: Nice, fixed more me as well.  I did `rvm list`, noticed it was on `jruby-9.3.8.0`, did `rvm use ruby-2.7.7` (The most recent non-JRuby), then it installed just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Only had JRuby installed, had to go with `rvm use system` before installing new CRuby version. And this was on Centos.

Comment: This step was the saviour for me and put an end to 1 day of struggle of upgrading Ruby